# CUDA threads per block limitation

Tags: cuda

Why I can't use max of `Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)`? If I use `(1024, 1024)` it doesn't work, and when I use `(32, 32)` or `(1, 1024)` etc. it works. Is it about shared memory?

Here is my result from deviceQuery:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 3 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "Tesla M2070"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.5 / 5.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 5375 MBytes (5636554752 bytes)
  (14) Multiprocessors, ( 32) CUDA Cores/MP:     448 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1147 MHz (1.15 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1566 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 786432 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65535), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Enabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           6 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

Device 1: "Tesla M2070"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.5 / 5.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 5375 MBytes (5636554752 bytes)
  (14) Multiprocessors, ( 32) CUDA Cores/MP:     448 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1147 MHz (1.15 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1566 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 786432 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65535), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Enabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           20 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

Device 2: "Tesla M2070"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.5 / 5.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 5375 MBytes (5636554752 bytes)
  (14) Multiprocessors, ( 32) CUDA Cores/MP:     448 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1147 MHz (1.15 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             1566 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 786432 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65535), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Enabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           17 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
> Peer access from Tesla M2070 (GPU0) -> Tesla M2070 (GPU1) : No
> Peer access from Tesla M2070 (GPU0) -> Tesla M2070 (GPU2) : No
> Peer access from Tesla M2070 (GPU1) -> Tesla M2070 (GPU1) : No
> Peer access from Tesla M2070 (GPU1) -> Tesla M2070 (GPU2) : Yes
> Peer access from Tesla M2070 (GPU1) -> Tesla M2070 (GPU0) : No
> Peer access from Tesla M2070 (GPU1) -> Tesla M2070 (GPU1) : No
> Peer access from Tesla M2070 (GPU2) -> Tesla M2070 (GPU0) : No
> Peer access from Tesla M2070 (GPU2) -> Tesla M2070 (GPU1) : Yes

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 5.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 5.5, NumDevs = 3, Device0 = Tesla M2070, Device1 = Tesla M2070, Device2 = Tesla M2070
Result = PASS
```

Comment: Where does this deviceQuery thingy come from?

Comment: Ans: clone the [CUDA samples repository](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples), `cd` into the `1_Utilities/deviceQuery` subfolder. Then run `make` to build the `deviceQuery` binary this question is about.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why I can't use max of Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)?

Because each one of those is an individual limit *for that dimension*.  There is an additional overall limit also indicated in your deviceQuery  printout:

```
Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
```

A threadblock is up to a 3-dimensional structure, so the total number of threads in a block is equal to the product of the individual dimensions that you choose.  This product must also be less than or equal to 1024 (and greater than 0).  This is just another hardware limit of the device.

> Is it about shared memory?

The above is unrelated to any usage of shared memory.  (Your code doesn't appear to be using shared memory anyway.)